# Show if $f(n)$ has polynomial growth and $g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$, then $g(n)$ also has polynomial growth

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

As stated in the question title, if $f(n)$ has polynomial growth and $g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$, then how can we show $g(n)$ also has polynomial growth?

$g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$ gives us $0\leq c_1f(n)\leq g(n)\leq c_2f(n)$ for some positive constants $c_1, c_2$ for some $n>n_0>0$. But how can I conclude $g(n)$ also satisfies the polynomial growth condition?

A function $f(n)$ defined on all sufficiently large positive reals satisfies the *polynomial-growth condition* if there exists a constant $\hat{n} > 0$ such that the following holds: for every constant $\phi \geq 1$, there exits a constant $d>1$ (depending on $\phi$) such that $f(n)/d \leq f(\psi n) \leq d f(n)$ for all $1 \leq \psi \leq \phi$ and $n \geq \hat{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider only sufficiently large values of $n$. As you have pointed out there are two constants $c_1, c_2$ with $0< c_1 \le c_2$ such that:
$$
c_1 f(n) \le g(n) \le c_2f(n).
$$

Also, since $f$ has polynomial growth, for every $\phi \ge 1$ there exists some  $d_\phi > 1$ such that:
$$
\frac{1}{d_\phi} f(n) \le f(\psi n) \le d_\phi f(n) \quad \forall 1 \le\psi \le \phi.
$$

Then the following holds for all $1 \le\psi \le \phi$:
$$
\frac{c_1}{c_2 d_\phi}  g(n)
\le \frac{c_1 }{d_\phi} f(n) \le c_1 f(\psi n) \le g(\psi n) \le c_2 f(\psi n)
 \le c_2 d_\phi f(n) \le \frac{c_2 d_\phi}{c_1} g(n).
$$
Which means that $g$ also satisfies the polynomial growth condition.
In particular, for a given $\phi$, we can choose $d'_\phi = \frac{c_2 d_\phi}{c_1}$ to obtain:
$$
\frac{1}{d'_\phi}  g(n) \le g(\psi n) \le d'_\phi g(n) \quad \forall 1 \le\psi \le \phi,
$$
where $d'_\phi > 1$ holds since $c_2 \ge c_1$ and $d_\phi > 1$.